# Escaping comma in numbers and not in strings

Tags: java

I am working on a project where i have to break a string containg both characters and integers

Say String string=hi,i have 1,000rs.

The above string have to be divided in to two strings as
    string1=hi
    string2=i have 1,000rs.
But with the below logic i am able to divide it as
    string1=hi
    string2=i have 1
    string3=000rs.
Can anyone please help me with this.

```
StringTokenizer strTokenizer=new StringTokenizer(string,",");    
while(strTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){    
String temp=strTokenizer.nextToken();    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
    String[] a = "Say String string=hi,i have 1,000rs.".split(",(?!\\d)");
    for(String e : a) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

output

```
Say String string=hi
i have 1,000rs.
```

**UPDATE**

`"(?<!\\d),|,(?!\\d)"` seems to be more reliable

Comment: That's a good answer but could you also explain a little bit about what you are doing so that the OP understands? *try* and then some code won't help the OP that much. Some clarifications please (regex etc.).

Comment: +1, but this won't work if the comma are near the numbers. e.g. "Hi, how are ,10,00 you".

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev you solution is working correctly I tested it in online compiler. Here is the link. http://ideone.com/eOstyl. +1 for your answer.

Comment: The o/p should be as 
hi
i have 1,000rs
2,000rs

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev No, this will fail on `Hi, how are ,10,00 you`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String s="hi,i have 1,000rs.";
String[] splitted =s.split(",(?=([^\\d]*\\d[^\\d]*\\d)*[^\\d]*$)");
for(String ss: splitted)
    System.out.println(ss);
```

Output:

```
hi
i have 1,000rs.
```

Comment: That's a good answer but could you also explain a little bit about what you are doing so that the OP understands? *Try this* and then some code won't help the OP that much. Some clarifications please (regex etc.).

Comment: @Achintya Jha.. That helped.. Thanks,But can u please let me know how that works..